# std::string::data() won't return a char*

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

As I fail to compile the following program, I wonder if:

- GCC 6.3.0 as not implemented C++17 feature `CharT* std::string::data()` yet;
- My code is not C++17 compliant.

According to [the documentation of `std::string::data()` on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data), since C++17 this function can return a non-const pointer to the *underlying array serving as character storage*.

#### Code

```
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string hello("world");
    char* data = hello.data();
    (void) data;
}
```

#### Compile with

```
g++ --version ; g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -Werror main.cpp
```

#### Output

```
g++ (GCC) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:6:28: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
     char* data = hello.data();
                  ~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

#### Demo

[Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6e7c405de10863f)

Comment: For somebody that well-versed in C++ dialects, standards and GCC, it shouldn't be too much of a problem to find GCC C++ support matrix, proudly available at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the reason for the post is unclear - certainly OP could find the support matrix themselves?

Comment: I am curious, not trying to be a jerk, is this different from the string * operator?

Comment: @SergeyA I'm not well-versed in C++ dialect. I did not know of the _GCC C++ support matrix_. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @YSC you can try latest g++ or clang online with the [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/X50jLJucebKN0erC)

Comment: @GradyPlayer what is "the string * operator" ?

Comment: @jonathanWakely I guess I meant the [] operator... I am std C guy, I am confused that the overload exists at all :)

Comment: @GradyPlayer one returns a reference to a character and one returns a pointer to a sequence of characters, so yes, they're different.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Grady meant --- I guess --- use `&str[0]` instead of `str.data()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the libstdc++ documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z), the feature you're looking for is implemented in libstdc++ version 7. It's listed as *Give 'std::string' a non-const '.data()' member function*, proposal [P0272R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0272r1.html).

Similarly, [the libc++ documentation](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html) lists the same proposal as implemented in libc++ version 3.9.

Comment: @SergeyA: If you think the question is bad, down-vote the question.

Comment: I did. But bad answers provide the supporting feedback loop to bad questions, so in order to get rid of the first, one has to also punish the second.

Comment: @SergeyA In what way exactly is this answer bad?

Comment: @SergeyA "I did" - yet the question is still positively ranked - just because you didn't find it a good question doesn't mean others didn't.
Just because you didn't find the question useful doesn't mean you should downvote good answers

Comment: @SergeyA How is this "spoon-feeding"? It's usually only problematic when this happens in a homework setting. This is just a good answer to OP's question, if "giving the necessary information to answer the question" is spoon-feeding according to you then you might as well downvote a lot a lot more detailed answers.

Comment: @SergeyA: Go ahead and down-vote accurate, helpful answers then. As for the question, it may be trivial but it is a good example of a clearly formulated and well-formatted question.

Comment: @SergeyA "_punish_"? Seriously??

Comment: @GillBates et all, yes, this is spoon feeding, and yes, the answer is googlable by 'gcc C++17 support status' query in a matter of seconds. And yes, I'd prefer stack overflow to **not** turn into LMGFY service, and yes, I would exercise my options which allow me downvote/VTC questions which are a google queries and yes, I would downvote answers to those questions as the questions appear hear **only** because they receive answers.

Comment: @GillBates I have to agree with SergeyA at least in regards to the question. The question is not good. OP didn't put any effort into finding it out himself, even though he stated the answer himself _"GCC 6.3.0 as not implemented C++17 feature CharT* std::string::data() yet;"_ He oviously did not even try to search for it. I still do disagree with downvoting a perfectly fine answer. IMHO: The question should be closed as "Offtopic: Why isn't this code working"